# Как проверить принадлежность слова к массиву?

Tags: javascript

Помогите,пожалуйста, решить проблему. ошибка в функции сортировке по длине.  Необходимо проверить является ли введенное в текстовое поле слово, совокупностью из элементов массива. Например, ввели слово "test1a", выводим сообщение "Слово существует", если ввели "test2a", то не существует.

```js
var arr = ['test', 'test1', 'a'];
array.innerHTML = arr;

function wordArray(){
     var x = document.getElementById('newArray');
     var str = document.getElementById("inputWord").value;
     var newArr = x.sort(function(a,b){
         return b.length - a.length;
     });
     var dpStr = str.slice();
     newArr.forEach(function(value){
         return dpStr.replace(value, "");
     });
     if (!dpStr){
         alert("Слово "+ str + "существует");
     } else {
         alert("Слово "+ str + " не существует");
     }
}
```

```html
<div id="array"></div>
<div id="newArray"></div>

<div class="checkWord">
       <form>
        <input type="text" id="inputWord">
        <input type="button" value="Проверить" onclick="wordArray()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос много раз. В ответе к прошлому вопросу есть рабочий пример. Обрати внимание на то, что конкретно там сортируется, и что пытаешься сортировать ты

Answer (score -1):

В двух словах, алгоритм такой:

```
word = "..."
rests = [word]
dict = [...]

while rests.length != 0:
  for r in rests:
    if r.lenght == 0:
      return true

    for i in dict:
      if r.startsWith(i):
        rests.push(r.replaceFirst(i))

    rests.erase(r) 

return false
```